# Type error: Type Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting this error while building on server 01, same code base is building and running  on server 02.

```
#0 15.14 Type error: Type '{ comments: void | Promise<any> | null; setTab: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; tab: string; likes: number | AxiosResponse<any, any>; path: string; emotionCache: EmotionCache; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

#0 15.14   Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

node version: v14.18.2
npm version: 6.14.15

not able to understand what mistake I'm doing, can someone please help me with this.

[image]

```js
import { ReactElement, ReactNode, useMemo, useState } from "react"
import { NextPage } from "next"
import { AppProps } from "next/app"
import Head from "next/head"
import { EmotionCache } from "@emotion/react"
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser"
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react"
import { createTheme, StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios"
import SideBarDrawer from "components/SideBarDrawer"
import AuthProvider from "context/AuthContext/AuthProvider"
import GlossaryProvider from "context/GlossaryContext/GlossaryProvider"
import LikesProvider from "context/LikesContext/LikesProvider"
import NewsletterProvider from "context/NewsletterContext/NewsletterProvider"
import TrackerProvider from "context/TrackerContext/TrackerProvider"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { msalConfig } from "utils/authConfig"
import createEmotionCache from "utils/createEmotionCache"
import { store } from "../../../store";

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
  comments?: any;
  setTab: () => void;
  tab: string;
  likes: any;
  path: string;
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}


const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);


const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, path }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  
  const [mode] = useState("black");
  const [comments, ] = useState<Promise<any> | null | void>(null);
  const [likes, ] = useState<AxiosResponse | number>(0);
  const [tab, setTab] = useState<string>('')


  const outerTheme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: {
            main: '#5da6f9'
          },
          neutral: {
            main: mode,
          },
          neutral2: {
            main: mode === 'black' ? '#fff' : '#000',
          }
        }
      }),
    [mode]
  );

  return (  
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
  <AuthProvider>
    <TrackerProvider>
      <NewsletterProvider>
        <LikesProvider>
          <GlossaryProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
              </Head>
              <ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme}>
                <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                  <SideBarDrawer>
                    <Component 
                      {...pageProps}
                      comments={comments}
                      setTab={setTab}
                      tab={tab}
                      likes={likes}
                      path={path}
                      emotionCache={emotionCache}
                    />
                  </SideBarDrawer>
                </StyledEngineProvider>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </Provider>
          </GlossaryProvider>
        </LikesProvider>
      </NewsletterProvider>
    </TrackerProvider>
  </AuthProvider>
  </MsalProvider>)
}

export default AppComponent
```

Comment: Your `NextPageWithLayout` doesn't have a `comments` prop. You might have to create your own type instead of using `NextPage`.

Comment: ​ Thanks for your comment, using custom type the error is not coming now. Do you have any idea why the same code is running in a different environment?